# HTTP Server Push with PHP / Apache2

Tags: php, .net, apache2, push

Is it possible to perform HTTP Push with Apache2+PHP? I've done some Googleing around and the only thing close to what i was looking for was a PECL Socket tutorial which didn't quite tackle what i was looking for.

My application at the moment has a basic read GET API, the client requests a read to the API once every 15 seconds. I think this is kind of silly as an open port that just sends data when there is data to send seems like a much better method. My client is written in .net.

Is this possible at all on these technologies? Or will i have to try and use java/comet, which at the moment i just don't have the resources / infrastructure readily available

More information on HTTP Server Push:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deciding between different technologies to report events from a HTTP server to a client there are allways tradeoffs to make: 150 Clients polling every 15 seconds with a poll taking 1s will statistically tie up 10 connections, the same 150 clients with a server push technology will tie up 150 connections but with much less CPU.

IMHO Long polling has the best balance if used in combination with Apache/PHP, as it allows for the server to influence the clients, if these are in your control: If the connection count on the server goes too high, it can just return the longest running poll and send information to the client to not repoll immediately, but with some delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a little unsure of what you mean with the Long Polling technique. Is that when the client that has been waiting for the longest is the first to get the response? Sorry im a little bit noobish :) With my current situation it will be max 20 clients. But i dont want to thrash the server with to many requests, so i want quick data, with fewer requests. Which i think your Long Polling technique may solve, but im not really sure what it is....

Comment: OK, what I mean by long polling is: On the client side you do exact the same thing that you do right now (apart from maybe adapting some timeouts an reducing the pause between 2 requests to say 500ms). On the server side, when a poll request comes in an there is nothing to report, you wait for some time (say 30 seconds). If during this time an event happens on the server you report that event and end the request. If not, you end the request after the timeout reporting "nothing to report"

Comment: Ahh ok that makes a lot of sense, thanks for taking the time to explain, i appreciate it :)